# Passing JS-array to PHP, then updating MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

I have a problem. The story so far:

**PHP1** reads an array from the database, that contains only integers - it has the following form:

[0, 70, 44, ...]

Because the number of entities it contains varies, I want to be able to read and store the whole array into one cell of the database - **the solution must not disregard this, then.**

**PHP1** contains some JS, that allows a user to do something on the website, which alters one of the entities in the array, which makes it, e.g.;

[0, ***75***, 44, ...]

So far, so good.

**Now I want this new array to replace the one in the database**, this is the central goal that I fail to achieve.

What I'm currently working with - which isn't working:

**PHP1** executes some AJAX magic, and sends this array to **PHP2**, which works fine:

```
var arrayX = [0, 75, 44, ...];
var arrayY = JSON.stringify(arrayX);

$.ajax({
    url: 'PHP2.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {arrayY: arrayY }
});
```

**PHP2** then connects to the DB, and attempts to update that one cell with the new array, by means of the following, which doesn't work (!):

```
$arrayZ = json_decode($_POST['arrayY'], true);

mysql_query("UPDATE userbase SET db_column = $arrayZ WHERE id=0", $con);

mysql_close($con);
```

I've tried serializing $arrayZ in PHP2, as well as a whole set of other solutions I found on Stackoverflow, but none of them worked (or I didn't apply them correctly of course) and now I've found myself deadstruck...

I'm hoping your talents will get me further than my own have!

Comment: Your database schema is flawed - having multivalued cells is a horrible idea.

Comment: "dont work" is not much...please provide more informations why it is not working

Comment: please do a print_r($_POST); at the top of PHP2 and post your output here.

Comment: it seems that you dont need to JSON.stringify because its already json

Comment: Steven, this is what I get: 

Array
(
    [arrayZ] => [1,70]
)
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../PHP2.php:3) in <b>.../PHP2.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at .../PHP2.php:3) in <b>.../PHP2.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />

Comment: and, about the stringify; if i don't, i get the warning that PHP2 expects a string, even though an array was given.

Answer (score 3):

I assume db_column holds a string value, and as such you probably just need quotes around $arrayZ in your SQL string.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE userbase SET db_column = '$arrayZ' WHERE id=0", $con);
```

But as Fake51 pointed out, your database schema is flawed.

Also, you're susceptible to a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: then the DB contains only 'array', instead of the actual array.

Comment: @victor Create a one-to-many relationship to store these values. What you're doing here is a bad idea.